# Chat server. Thread issue

Tags: java, sockets, chat

Hi could somebody help me with this code because I was trying with If statement but is no working. I am not asking to write for me code just point me at something.

The main problem is that every time somebody connect, new thread is made but when he turn off his chat box the tread stays on and is not working as should be. I mean some body make 10 connections himself and nobody else can chat.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myServer {

    static ServerSocket server;
    static Socket client;
    static DataInputStream in;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static clientThread t[] = new clientThread[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting Server");
        server = new ServerSocket(7555);
        System.out.println("Started Server");

        while (true) {

            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("CONNECTION");
            out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Welcome to the chat room");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                if (t[i] == null) {
                    (t[i] = new clientThread(client, t)).start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

class clientThread extends Thread {

    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    static String msg;
    Socket client = null;
    clientThread t[];

    public clientThread(Socket client, clientThread[] t) {
        this.client = client;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            boolean tru = true;

            while (tru) {
                msg = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(msg);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
                    if (t[i] != null) {
                        t[i].out.writeUTF(msg);
                        System.out.println(t[i]);
                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not that the thread stays on, but rather that you have no mechanism for marking your client threads as finished.  Even though the thread has exited, `t[i]` will not become `null`.  It will still refer to an instance of a thread--just a "dead" thread.

Here's are two ways to fix it:

1. Just before your thread exits, mark `t[i] = null` (where `i` is the index of the current thread).  Note that you'll need to store the value of `i` in each thread.

   1. Modify `clientThread` and add `private int threadIndex;` as a member variable.
   2. Modify `clientThread`'s constructor and add `threadIndex` as a parameter.

      ```
      public clientThread(Socket client, clientThread[] t, int threadIndex) 
      {
          this.threadIndex=threadIndex;
          //...
      }
      ```
   3. Right before the closing brace of `run`, add

      ```
      synchronized(t){t[this.threadIndex]=null;}
      ```
2. Use an `Executor` and submit your `clientThread`s to it.  Java's `Executor`s will handle cleaning up threads for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating 10 threads for only one socket connection?  I think you'd want to create a single ClientThread per incoming connection to the chat server.  Then add that single ClientThread to a List of active chats.  When the chat client terminates the session, then remove the entry from that List.  You don't need to pass the Thread instance, or the array of ClientThreads to the constructor of ClientThread because that is itself.  Simply pass the Socket instance to ClientThread, and a reference to the ChatServer.  If you are trying to create a chat room.  Then allow the server to handle sending a message to everyone else:

```
public class ChatServer {
    List<ClientThread> activeParticipants;

    public void say( ClientThread author, String message ) {
        for( ClientThread current : activeParticipants ) {
           if( current != author ) {
              current.send( message ); // this method will send a message to that client
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll either need to use two threads, or use InputStream.available() method to check to see if some input is on either System.in or your socket's input stream.  That will allow you to read messages coming in as well as allowing a user to type a message at the same time.  Blocking on read() method would mean you couldn't see messages until you enter some data or receive data.

Also move the welcome message into the ClientThread so you don't call Socket.getOutputStream() twice using two different DataOutputStreams.

Answer (score 0):

You call method client.getOutputStream() twice, building each time a DataOutputStream. Try to welcome the user directly in the ClientThread.